# Turtle graphics module not found when run via terminal - Macos Mojave

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

So im using Macos Mojave, I tried writing some codes on Atom text editor that uses **import turtle** but when i run it on terminal, it says

```
    import Turtle
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Turtle'
```

But when i tried running it in IDLE, it works perfectly.

What should I do to make it work to work in the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Try `import turtle` with a lowercase t.

Comment: Glad I could help. An upvote and an approved answer would be great! Thanks :)